# How to disable function calling of selector in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, selector

I have set a function in a selector. After a function call I want to not call selector. I wrote this line of code but it is throwing an exception:

```
self.touchselector = nil;
```

How can I reset the function of selector in cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[NSNotification cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(powerHide) object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you scheduled a selector similarly to this:

```
[self scheduleSelector:@selector(onTouch:) interval:1];
```

Then you can unschedule that particular selector in the method that it calls via _cmd:

```
-(void) onTouch:(ccTime)delta
{
    // this will stop onTouch from being called every second
    [self unscheduleSelector:_cmd];
}
```